# Порядок выполнения кода

Tags: python, python-3.x

Не могу понять, пишу совсем недавно

```
user_list = ['0', 0, 0]

@bot.message_handler(commands=['help', 'start'])
def send_welcome(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Hello i`m bot !\n\nWhat`s your coin ? ')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, func_1)

def func_1(message):
    # global coin, user_list
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'quant ? ')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, func_2)
    coin = message.text
    user_list[0] = coin
    print(coin)

def func_2(message):
    # global quant, user_list
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'e_cost ? ')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, func_final)
    quant = float(message.text)
    user_list[1] = quant
    print (quant)

def func_final(message):
    # global e_cost, user_list
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'it`s over ! ')
    e_cost = float(message.text)
    user_list[2] = e_cost
    print (e_cost)
    # print (user_list)
    return user_list



if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

как мне вытащить готовый список 'user_list' из функции ? с включенным global
ситуация не меняется.

Comment: Замените изображение текстом.

Comment: У вас функция func_final возвращает список всё дальше с этой функцией работайте как со списком можете сделать даже так user_list = func_final()

Comment: Спасибо, помогло